# PHP upload to rackspace CDN

Tags: php, cdn, rackspace-cloud, rackspace

I recently bought a rackspace cloud server, how do I use a PHP script to upload files(images,videos) to my cloudfiles account.

Comment: http://docs.rackspace.com/files/api/v1/cf-devguide/content/Using_cURL-d1e2863.html The API guide, if that helps.

Answer (score 6):

There are examples on the [Rackspace Docs site](http://docs.rackspace.com/files/api/v1/cf-devguide/content/Using_cURL-d1e2863.html) for using curl. You can also find PHP examples [here](http://www.thetutorialblog.com/php/uploading-files-to-rackspace-cloud-mosso-using-php-api/).

Answer (score 0):

If you use any framework you can try codeigniter and the [cloudmanic-storage spark](https://github.com/cloudmanic/cloudmanic-storage)